# Can't set step property in input type number iside alert

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an input type number inside an Ionic v4 alert, the problem is that I can't set step property since It's not recognised, is there any workaround or solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have advanced alert needs you might consider making a modal form instead.

The alert doesn't have many configuration options.

I don't see the value in trying to recreate a full modal tutorial here. [This seems to cover it quite well](https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/how-to-declare-and-use-modals-in-ionic-v4-4d3f42ac30a3).

But the high level overview is that instead of using an alert you create what is basically a new page, but it is loaded in on top of the existing page and you can pass data in and out of it.